# Has the Linga Purana ,Vayu Purana and Aditya Purana criticized the Pancharātra Scripture?

Tags: pancharatra

I'm really interested to know of the Puranas which criticize the Pancharātra, especially the verses from Linga and Aditya Puranas. Since I got to know so from the following link,
https://www.wisdomlib.org/hinduism/book/a-history-of-indian-philosophy-volume-3/d/doc209938.html#note-e-29010

Also, are there verses criticizing Pancharātra from Smritis like Harita Or Usana ?

Comment: links are not a question

Comment: The question is very clearly mentioned in the body as well as in the title @SwamiVishwananda

Comment: Devi Bhagavtam's criticism can be found in this answer (https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/26429) .. I did not feel to include that here in this answer too

Answer (score 4):

This is a partial answer ..

The Usana Smriti has indeed criticized  the followers of some doctrines like Pancharatra as follows:

> The following are disqualified to be present at a S'raddha ceremony :
> Those, who sell the S'ruti', those, who marry widows ; those, who
> enter into a locked room without the permission of the owner ; and
> those, who officiate as priests for inferior castes ; are described as
> out-castes. Those, who teach unknown persons ; those, who give
> instructions on receiving fees ; those, who study the Vedas by paying
> fees ; are described as Vritakas. The Sramanas (Bouddha ascetics) ;
> Nirgoodas, (a class of naked mendicants) ; **those, who, know the
> doctrines of the Pancharatra** ;* the Jinas ;* the Kapalikas the
> Pasupatas  -if these, and similar other heretics, wicked souls
> pervaded by the quality of Tamas, partake of the Havi, the S'rdddha
> does not become successful, and it does not yield fruits in the next
> world.

The above verses are from Chapter 4 of the text and are stating that followers of such a doctrine are degraded and hence unfit to be invited in a Shraddha ceremony.

Answer (score 0):

`I'm really interested to know of the Puranas which criticize the Pancharātra`

**Yes.**

Several texts provide criticism for several philosophies of Vaishnavasim and other sects like Shaivism and Shaktism too. I'm giving references from two Puranas, not the ones though which have been *"especially-asked for in the question"*.

1. The Kurma Purana criticizes the Pancharatra, along with Jainas, Kapalikas, and Yamalas.

> Kurma Purana 1.12.262
>
> > 262. They i.e., **those contrary to the Vedas are the cults of Kapala, Bhairava, [Pancharatras], Yamala, Vama, and Arhata (Jaina).**
>
> > 263. In another incarnation of mine, these scriptures have been promulgated by me to delude the people who themselves try to mislead
> >      the other persons by propagating their false scriptures.
>
> [English Translation](https://archive.org/details/kurma-purana-full-parts-1-and-2/page/118/mode/1up) by Motilala Banarasidass Publications

---

2. The Devi Bhagavata-Purana

> [Devi Bhagavatam 11.1](https://archive.org/details/DeviBhagavataWithHindiTranslationVolume2GitaPress/page/n663/mode/1up)
>
> ये कुशास्त्राभियोगेन वर्तयन्तीह मानवान् ॥ २९ ॥ अधोमुखोर्ध्वपादास्ते
> यास्यन्ति नरकार्णवम् । कामाचाराः पाशुपतास्तथा वै लिङ्‌गधारिणः ॥ ३० ॥
> **तप्तमुद्राङ्‌किता ये च वैखानसमतानुगाः** । ते सर्वे निरयं यान्ति
> वेदमार्गबहिष्कृताः ॥ ३१ ॥ वेदोक्तमेव सद्धर्मं तस्मात्कुर्यान्नरः सदा ।
> उत्थायोत्थाय बोद्धव्यं किं मयाद्य कृतं कृतम् ॥ ३२ ॥
>
> > Those who do injury to others even by the blade of a Kuśa grass used
> > as a weapon, go to hell with their heads downwards and their feet
> > upwards. Those that follow their own sweet free will, that take up any
> > sort of dress (e. g. Bauddhas), **those that follow the philosophical
> > doctrines called Pāśupatas, and the other hermits and saints and
> > persons that take up other vows contrary to the religions of the
> > Vedas, for example, the Vaikhānasa followers, [those who brand their
> > bodies by the hot Mudrās], at the places of pilgrimages,** e. g. Dvārkā,
> > etc., they go to hell with their bodies scorched by red hot brands
> > (Tapta Mudrās). So persons should act according to the excellent
> > religions commanded by the Vedas.
>
> [English Translation](https://www.wisdomlib.org/hinduism/book/devi-bhagavata-purana/d/doc57379.html) by Swami Vijnananda

Here, although Pancharatra is not directly criticized, I think, the reference to `those who brand their bodies by the hot Mudrās` points to the *Pancharatrins* only. Besides, another sect within Vaishnavism known as - Vaikhanasa has been along with others.

---