# What are the Puranic verses which say Tapta Mudra Dharana should be done?

Tags: rituals, vaishnavism, sri-vaishnava, practice, vaikhanasa

[This question](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/22801/27724) asks what are the puranic verses that advise against Tapta Mudra Dharana.

I want to ask, what are the Puranic verses which say Tapta Mudra Dharana should be done?

Please answer with the exact Puranic chapter and verse along with a link that points to the verse. You can also include verses from Vedas, Upanishads, Smritis, and Agamas. But Puranas are the important ones which are words of Veda Vyasa.

There are some allegations that there are no such things in Puranas, and whatever is there is actually adulterated. So please quote from neutral sources like Gita Press or Well known popular editions or Old Manuscripts etc.

---

These are sources I got on the internet, but it does not give the chapter and verse number.

[This link](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&source=web&rct=j&url=https://www.sumadhwaseva.com/wp-content/uploads/2009/06/tapta-mudradharane.pdf&ved=2ahUKEwik5YyE6r74AhUkwjgGHc7ZC4YQFnoECAYQAQ&usg=AOvVaw0mm1TmKQIn724zu4dBBQDO) gives a list of Puranas endorsing it.

```
17. Importance of Mudradharana – some quotes :

a. Those who scolds/disrespects the one with Mudradharana, would be 
getting the sin of disrespecting/scolding Srihari.  

b. One who does not have Taptamudradharana will not have Vedadyana 
adhikara.   

c. Even during antya samskara time also Tapta mudradharana to be done 
(by Mudradharana) which will remove the fear of Yama and his 
servants.   

d. We should invite for Bhojana only those who has Mudra, lest it should 
be bhojana for pitru with mala mootra. 

e. As per Vamana Purana - the one who wears Sudarshana Chakra Mudra 
even for playing would get Vishnu loka  

f. As per Shivapurana - All those who are singing, praying the mahima of 
Srihari would be having Mudra.  

g. As per Skanda purana – One who has Chakradi ayudhaas, even if he has 
done so many sins, Yama will not come near him. The shareera which 
has Shanka-Chakra will be the home for gods.   

h. As per Padmapurana - Uttarakhanda quote – Shiva told Parvathi “Those 
who have agnitapta Vishnuchakra would be a Mahatmya.  

i. As per Markandeya Purana – Tapta Mudharana indicates the 
relationship between Srihari and us. It is similar to ladies wearing 
bangles, kumkuma, etc as the symbol of “muthaide”. Similarly those 
who have mudra would be recognized as “Vaishnava”.    

j. As per Matsyapurana – Vishnubhakta should have Chakra to his right 
shoulder and Shanka to his left shoulder, which would fetch him 
Vishnuloka.     

k. As per Skanda Purana – Even shoodras who possess Shanka Chakra 
symbol would get Svarga.

l. Kanyadaana to be done only for one who has Mudradharana.    

m. As per Smruti muktavali – One who does sandhyavandana, japa, homa, 
etc with Ordhwapundra dharana, - he will not get any punya. Entire 
punya would be taken away by raakshasas.
```

Shri Madhavacharya in his [Sarva Darshana Sangraha](https://archive.org/details/Sarva-Darsana-Samgraha.by.Madhavacharya-Vidyaranya.tr.by.E.B.Cowell/page/n100/mode/1up), page 92, while speaking on Purna Prajna Siddhanta he quotes Taittiriya Upanishad and Agneya Purana.

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Yes. Certainly, we do have *Paurāṇic* verses prescribing for the *Tapta-mudrā-vidhāna* for the *Vaiṣṇavas*.

### 1. Skanda-Purāṇa:

> ##### [Chapter 6,](https://www.wisdomlib.org/hinduism/book/the-skanda-purana/d/doc370685.html#note-t-139139) 
>   Veṅkaṭācala-māhātmya, Vaiṣṇava-khaṇḍa, Skanda-purāṇa
>
> Verse 2.1.6.51
>
> भक्तानां लक्षणं मातः शृणु गुह्यं समाहिता । शंखचक्रांकिता नित्यं
> भुजयुग्मे वसुन्धरे ॥ ५१ ॥
>
> > 51. **Listen to the marks of the devotees attentively, O Mother. It is a secret, O Dharaṇī. They have permanent marks of conch and discus on
> >     the pair of arms.**
>
> ---
>
> Verse 2.1.6.63-68
>
> हुत्वा महाव्याहृतिभिश्चक्रादींस्तत्र तापयेत् । सह्यान्सुतप्तान्गुरुणा
> मंत्रवद्धारयेद्बुधः ॥ ६३ ॥
>  भुजद्वये शंखचक्रे मूर्ध्नि शार्ङ्गशरौ
> तथा । ललाटे तु गदा धार्या हृदये खड्गमेव च ॥ ६४ ॥
>  एवं धार्याणि
> पञ्चैव विष्णुभक्तैर्मुमुक्षुभिः । अथवा भुजयोश्चक्र शंखौ चैव सुलक्षणौ ॥
> ६५ ॥
>  एवं लाञ्छनयुक्ता ये भक्तास्ते वैष्णवाः स्मृताः । तैरेव लभ्यं
> तद्ब्रह्म सदाचारसमन्वितैः ॥ ६६ ॥
>  तस्मिन्नेव मम
> प्रीतिस्तत्प्राप्तिं कांक्षते मनः । मातर्विष्णुविनान्येषु वाञ्छा
> काचिन्न जायते ॥ ६७ ॥
>  स्मरामि श्यामलं विष्णुं वदामि हरिमच्युतम् ।
> तेनैव मातर्जीवामि तद्योगे चिन्त्यतां विधिः ॥ ६८ ॥
>
> > - 63-68. After performing the Homa with Mahāvyāhṛtis (i.e. the great utterances, viz. Oṃ Bhūḥ Bhuvaḥ Svaḥ) **he should heat the discus etc.
> >   The learned devotee then shall bear the impressions when they have
> >   been heated well by the preceptor and the heat can be borne.** The
> >   impressions shall be received like the Mantras. The conch should be
> >   imprinted on one arm, the discus on the other, the Śārṅga bow with the
> >   arrow on the head, the mace on the forehead and the sword on the heart
> >   (chest). **These five impressions should be borne by the devotees of
> >   Viṣṇu desirous of salvation or the impressions of conch and discus
> >   shall be borne on both the arms.** They must be of good shape and clear.
> >   Those who have impressions like these are known as devotees and
> >   followers of Viṣṇu.

The *Purāṇa* further says that all the deeds by a *Dvija* are fruitless if performed without five qualifications, one of which is the *Tapta-mudrās*

> [Verse 2.5.3.56b-61](https://www.wisdomlib.org/hinduism/book/the-skanda-purana/d/doc371682.html)
>
> ##### Chapter 3, 
> Mārgaśīrṣa-māhātmy, Vaiṣṇava-khaṇḍa, Skanda-purāṇa
>
> उपवीतादिवद्धार्याः शंखचक्रगदाः सदा ॥ ५६ ॥
>  ब्राह्मणैश्च विशेषेण
> वैष्णवैश्च विशेषतः ।
> **उपवीतं शिखा यद्वच्चक्रं लांछन संयुतम् ॥ ५७ ॥**
> **चक्रलांछनहीनस्य विप्रस्य विफलं भवेत् ।**
>  मम चक्रांऽकितो देहः पवित्र इति वै श्रुतिः ॥ ५८ ॥
>  चक्रांऽकिताय दातव्यं हव्यं कव्यं
> विचक्षणैः ।
>  मम चक्रांऽककवचमभेद्यं देवदानवैः ।
>  अजेयः
> सर्वभूतानां शत्रूणां रक्षसामपि ॥ ५९ ॥
>  मम चक्रांऽककवचं शरीरे यस्य
> तिष्ठति ।
>  नाऽशुभं विद्यते तस्य गृहपुत्रादिकस्य हि ॥ ६० ॥
> दक्षिणे च भुजे विप्रो बिभृयाद्वै सुदर्शनम् ।
>  सव्ये च शंखं
> बिभृयादिति वेदविदो विदुः ॥ ६१ ॥
>
> > - 56b-59. The conch, the discus, and the iron club are to be worn like the
> >   sacred thread always, particularly by Brāhmaṇas and still more
> >   , particularly by Vaiṣṇavas. **As is the sacred thread or the tuft, so is the discus along with the
> >   imprints. (Everything done by) a Brāhmaṇa devoid of the discus and the
> >   imprints shall be futile. The Vedas ever declare that the body marked with
> >   my discus is sanctified. Havya and Kavya should be offered to one who is
> >   marked with the discus.** The coat of mail marked with my discus cannot be
> >   broken or pierced by Devas or Dānavas. He is invisible to all living
> >   beings, enemies and Rākṣasas too.
> >
> > 60. If the coat of mail (or amulet) marked with my discus is present on anyone’s body, no inauspicious thing will occur to him or to his
> >     house, sons and others.
> > 61. **Those who know the Vedas know that a Brāhmaṇa should wear Sudarśana on his right arm and the conch on his left arm.**
>
> English Translation by G.V. Tagare
> *([Motilal Banarsidass Publishers](https://archive.org/details/dli.bengal.10689.13009/page/n39/mode/2up))*

---

### 2. Padma-Purāṇa:

Almost the whole chapter is devoted to define the importance of heated-marks (*tapta-mudras*).

> ##### [Chapter 224,](https://www.wisdomlib.org/hinduism/book/the-padma-purana/d/doc365808.html) 
>  Uttara-Khaṇḍa, Padma-purāṇa.
>
> > Rudra said:
>
> Verse 6.224.29-34
>
> तच्चिह्नैरंकितः श्रीशपदंप्राप्नोत्यसंशयम् । शंखचक्रांकनं
> कुर्याद्ब्राह्मणो बाहुमूलयोः ॥ २९ ॥ हुताग्निनैव संतप्य
> सर्वपापापनुत्तये । चक्रं वा शंखचक्रे वा तथा पंचायुधानि वा ॥ ३० ॥
> धारयित्वैव विधिवद्व्रह्मकर्मसमारभेत् । अग्नितप्तं पवित्रं च धृत्वा वै
> भुजमूलयोः ॥ ३१ ॥ त्यक्त्वा यमपुरं घोरं याति विष्णोः परं पदम् ।
> चक्रचिह्नविहीनस्तु यः पूजयति केशवम् ॥ ३२ ॥ तत्सर्वं विफलं याति
> पूजामंत्रजपादिकम् । अग्नितप्तेन चक्रेण ब्राह्मणो बाहुमूलयोः ॥ ३३ ॥
> अंकयित्वा जपन्मंत्रं संसारान्मोक्षमाप्नुयात् । सुदर्शनं धारयित्वा
> वह्नितप्तं द्विजोत्तमः ॥ ३४ ॥
>
> > - 29-34. Having marks of his signs he doubtlessly reaches the feet (or the position) of the lord of Lakṣmī. **A brāhmaṇa should have the marks
> >   of a conch and a disc at the roots of his arms, (and) for removing all
> >   sins the marks should be made after these are heated in fire. Having
> >   duly put on the mark of a disc or a conch and a disc or of the five
> >   weapons (of Viṣṇu), he should begin his religious duties.** Having worn
> >   the mark of the disc heated in fire at the roots of his arms, he
> >   avoids the fearful city of Yama, and goes to the highest position of
> >   Viṣṇu. All that worship, hymns, muttering (of hymns) of him who
> >   worships Viṣṇu without (having on his body) the mark of a disc perish
> >   es. The brāhmaṇa who having marked (his body) at the roots of arms
> >   with a disc heated in fire, (then) mutters the hymn, would obtain
> >   salvation. The best brāhmaṇa having put on the mark of Sudarśana disc
> >   heated in fire and having duly made offerings should appoint (a
> >   brāhmaṇa) for the rites.
>
> ---
>
> Verse 6.224.47-50
>
> प्रतप्तं बिभृयाच्चक्रं शंखं च भुजमूलयोः । स्त्रीशूद्राणां सदा धार्य्ये
> चंदनेन सुगंधिना ॥ ४७ ॥
>  बाहुमूले लिखेच्चक्रं तप्तं तु ब्राह्मणस्य
> वै । तप्तेनैवांकनं कुर्याद्ब्राह्मणस्य विधानतः ॥ ४८ ॥
> श्रौतस्मार्त्तादिसिद्ध्यर्थं मंत्रसिद्ध्यै तथैव च । हरेः
> पूजाधिकारार्थं चक्रं धार्यां विधानतः ॥ ४९ ॥
>  वैष्णवत्वस्य
> सिद्ध्यर्थं ज्ञानसिद्ध्यर्थमेव च । प्रतपेच्चक्रशंङ्खाभ्यां हुत्वा होमं
> विधानतः ॥ ५० ॥
>
> > - 47-50. **He should have, at the roots of his arms, the marks made with heated disc and conch**. Women and śūdras should always have those made
> >   with scented sandal (-paste). **At the root of the arm of a brāhmaṇa the
> >   mark of the disc should be made with a heated (sign). Marks with
> >   heated (signs) must be duly made (on the body) of a brāhmaṇa.** For the
> >   success in (rites prescribed by) the holy and the Smṛti texts, so also
> >   for being entitled to worshipping Viṣṇu, (the mark of) the disc should
> >   be duly had. **For accomplishing the status of Viṣṇu, and for getting
> >   knowledge, a man should burn his body with (i.e. have marks of) heated
> >   conch and disc,** after duly having offered oblations into fire.
>
> English Translation by N.A. Deshpande
> *([Published by Motilal Banarsidass Publishers Private Limited](https://archive.org/details/dli.bengal.10689.12954/page/n205/mode/2up))*